# T-SQL OPENJSON $ AS JSON not working

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Can anyone tell me why the first example works, but the second doesn't? To me they look like they should equate to the same thing...

```
DECLARE @prmInputData NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{ "a": { "b": 1, "c": 2 } }'

SELECT b, c, a
FROM OPENJSON(@prmInputData, '$')
WITH (
  b INT '$.a.b',
  c INT '$.a.c',
  a NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.a' AS JSON
)

SELECT b, c, a
FROM OPENJSON(@prmInputData, '$.a')
WITH (
  b INT '$.b',
  c INT '$.c',
  a NVARCHAR(MAX) '$' AS JSON
)
```

The first example returns "a" as a JSON object, correctly.

The second example returns "a" as NULL, incorrectly.

I'm not sure why!

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to spot the difference is to omit `WITH` part

Your original query:

```
DECLARE @prmInputData NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{ "a": { "b": 1, "c": 2 } }';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@prmInputData, '$')
WITH (
  b INT '$.a.b',
  c INT '$.a.c',
  a NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.a' AS JSON
);

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@prmInputData, '$.a')
WITH (
  b INT '$.b',
  c INT '$.c',
  a NVARCHAR(MAX) '$' AS JSON
);
```

Output:

```
╔═══╦═══╦════════════════════╗
║ b ║ c ║         a          ║
╠═══╬═══╬════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 2 ║ { "b": 1, "c": 2 } ║
╚═══╩═══╩════════════════════╝

 vs 

╔═══╦═══╦══════╗
║ b ║ c ║  a   ║
╠═══╬═══╬══════╣
║ 1 ║ 2 ║ NULL ║
╚═══╩═══╩══════╝
```

---

After removing `WITH`:

```
DECLARE @prmInputData NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{ "a": { "b": 1, "c": 2 } }';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@prmInputData, '$');

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@prmInputData, '$.a');
```

Result:

```
╔═════╦════════════════════╦══════╗
║ key ║       value        ║ type ║
╠═════╬════════════════════╬══════╣
║ a   ║ { "b": 1, "c": 2 } ║    5 ║      -- 5 ObjectValue
╚═════╩════════════════════╩══════╝

 vs

╔═════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ key ║ value ║ type ║
╠═════╬═══════╬══════╣
║ b   ║     1 ║    2 ║                   -- 2 IntValue
║ c   ║     2 ║    2 ║                   -- 2 IntValue
╚═════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

Now you can check how path behaves `'$.a'` vs `'$'`.

---

From [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql):

> If you want to return a nested JSON fragment from a JSON property, you
>   have to provide the AS JSON flag. **Without this option, if the property
>   can't be found, OPENJSON returns a NULL value instead of the
>   referenced JSON object or array, or it returns a run-time error in
>   strict mode .**

So trying second with strict mode:

```
DECLARE @prmInputData NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{ "a": { "b": 1, "c": 2 } }';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@prmInputData, '$.a')
WITH  (
  b INT '$.b',
  c INT '$.c',
  a NVARCHAR(MAX) 'strict $' AS JSON
);
```

It will end up with error:

> Property cannot be found on the specified JSON path.

Comment: Ah that's interesting, thank you. So is there any way to select multiple layers like I want in the same OPENJSON query?